# SVG button affects external div display

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to implement the

http://demosthenes.info/blog/760/Create-A-Responsive-Imagemap-With-SVG

to my needs

The problem is that I want the button Ive created to change the style of a div outside the figure tag. I can not find a way to do that.

All I need is by hovering over the .my-1 button, to display the .y1 div

Here is the code so far.

```
<style type="text/css">

#burj-imagemap {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 75%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
}

#burj-imagemap svg {
    display: inline-block;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.my-1:hover {background:#fff; z-index:100; opacity:0.3; filter: alpha(opacity=30); border:1px solid #000;
}

.my-1 {cursor: pointer;}

.y1 {
    display: none;
}
.my-1:hover .y1 {
    display: block;
    background-color: #F00;
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    z-index:1000;
}

</style>

<figure id="burj-imagemap">
<svg preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 1200 808" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
<image xlink:href="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/burj-khalifa.jpg" height="808" width="1200">
</image>
<a class="my-1" >
<g>
    <defs>
        <polygon id="SVGID_1_" points="322,131 62,240 79,346 274,250 412,405 501,250"/>
    </defs>
    <clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
        <use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_"  overflow="visible"/>
    </clipPath>
    <g clip-path="url(#SVGID_2_)">
        <image overflow="visible" width="1200" height="808" xlink:href="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/burj-khalifa.jpg"  transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -33.5 -301)">
        </image>
    </g>
</g></a>
</svg>
</figure>
<div class="y1">Hi!</div>
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could include an event handler in the svg like this..

```
<g clip-path="url(#SVGID_2_)" onmouseover="document.getElementById('y1').style['display'] = 'inline';">
<div id="y1" class="y1">Hi!</div>
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/9mDur/